# Does $\mathbb{P}(X \in B)=\mathbb{P}(Y\in B)$ for all $B \in \mathcal{B}$ implies $X=Y$ almost surely?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $X,Y: (\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})\to (\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B})$ be random variables. Does $\mathbb{P}(X \in B)=\mathbb{P}(Y\in B)$ for all $B \in \mathcal{B}$ implies $X=Y$ almost surely?

Comment: What is your opinion on this?

Comment: @nejimban This should be true, but I'm not able to proof it

Comment: You may have more luck in showing this is false.

Comment: ok thanks, I guess I got a counterexample with symmetric distribution

Comment: When $\mathbb{P}(X \in B)=\mathbb{P}(Y\in B)$ for all $B$ we say $X,Y$ are equal in distribution; or $X,Y$ are identically distributed.  As you continue to study probability, you will see this situation a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is no. To say that $P(X\in B)=P(Y\in B)$ for all $B\in \mathcal B$ is to say that $X$ and $Y$ are equal in distribution. This means they have the same marginal distributions. $X$ and $Y$ do not even need to be defined on the same probability space for this to make sense.

To say that $X=Y$ is to say something very specific about the *joint* distribution of $X$ and $Y$. This requires both $X$ and $Y$ to be defined on the same probability space. It is a special case of $X$ and $Y$ having a correlation of $+1$, the maximum possible correlation; when $X$ increases, so does $Y$.

The following example illustrates the difference, and is good to keep in mind. Flip two coins. Let $X$ be the number of heads, and let $Y$ be the number of tails. Then $X$ and $Y$ are equi-distributed, but $X=Y$ does not always hold. In this case, $X$ and $Y$ are perfectly *negatively* correlated.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the probability space $([0,1],\mathscr{B}([0,1]),\lambda)$ where $\mathscr{B}([0,1])$ is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra and $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure.  Define $X(t)=\mathbb{1}_{[0,1/2]}(t)$ and $Y(t)=\mathbb{1}_{(1/2,1]}(t)$, where $\mathbb{1}_A$ is the indicator function of set $A$. Then $\lambda(X\in B)=\lambda(Y\in B)$ for all $B\in\mathscr{B}([0,1])$; and yet $X(t)\neq Y(t)$ for all $t\in[0,1]$.

$X$ and $Y$ have the same distribution. In that sense, one says that $X$ and $Y$ are equal in distribution.